# when .load() same page, click trigger twice in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

this is my main page html:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a href="#" class="MyClick">Parent Click</a></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('.MyClick').click(function(){
       $('.content').load('page2.html');
    }); 
  })
</script>
```

and this is page2.html

```js
<a href="#" class="showoff">Child Click</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){      
    $('.showoff').live('click',function(){
        console.log('I Clicked');
    });     
 });
</script>
```

when link `parent click` clicked, load `page2.html` into `div.content` and when `child click` cliked print in console firebug once..

but my problem is when I click again `parent click` and click again `child click`,
in console print twice however I click once, it's like `page2.html` before not yet remove from DOM and `child click` in page2.html before fired together with a new one..

I want to how many time I load `page2.html` it's not print multiple line when I just click once `Child click`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you load `page2.html` you register a delegate click handler for `.showoff` since you use `.live()`(which is deprecated by the way, use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for version < 1.7), that's why you get multiple prints per clicks.

Are you using live for a specific purpose? Cause it seems unnecessary to me, just use a handler on the element itself.

```
<a href="#" class="showoff">Child Click</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){      
    $('.showoff').on('click',function(){
        console.log('I Clicked');
    });     
 });
</script>
```